# In Firefox Developers Tools, in the Network Monitor, the tab Preview is always empty

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, network-monitoring

I'm using "Firefox Developers Tools" to debug my webapps. The tab Network Monitor show all request, and in each one I can see Headers, Cookies, Responses, Timing but the Preview tab not show the content, it's always empty, else even when the Response (from server) is an html.

[image: the response of the request]
[image: the preview tab is empty]

Who ever happened something similar?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently only HTTPS sourced pages are rendered in preview. I am figuring out how to resolve this for local development for one week now. Dont want to port back to Chrome couse it is really slow but if i cant resolve this ... will have to.

Comment: Hi Jernej. Thank you for your answers. You right. I tested with page over HTTPS and the preview works fine!

Is it a Firefox bug?

Comment: yeah it look like its only Firefox bug... already posted a bug on their bugzilla

Comment: Same issue. It's doing my head in!! Going back to Chrome since it's been confirmed as a bug.

Comment: Does someone have a link to the bug report?